# Ampscript add user to a list

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to create a ET landing page that adds a user to a Data Extension and a List upon submission. I believe I have the adding to a Data Extension part down, i'm looking for some help understanding how to add a user to a list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This post should help you: [How do I add subscriber to a suppression list with ampscript in a landing page](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/60639/5202)

Comment: Here's the search I used: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bampscript%5D+list+subscriber+add

Comment: I believe I looked at that post before, will this allow me to add to a normal list and not a publication list?

Comment: Both are List Objects, so yes.

Comment: If this works, could you write it up as the answer, so future visitors clearly see it? Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I can add to a list under My Lists, but not to a Publication List.